# Losing types on sequencing Futures

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to do this:

```
  case class ConversationData(members: Seq[ConversationMemberModel], messages: Seq[MessageModel])

  val membersFuture: Future[Seq[ConversationMemberModel]] = ConversationMemberPersistence.searchByConversationId(conversationId)

  val messagesFuture: Future[Seq[MessageModel]] = MessagePersistence.searchByConversationId(conversationId)

  Future.sequence(List(membersFuture, messagesFuture)).map{ result =>
    // some magic here

    self ! ConversationData(members, messages)
  }
```

But when I'm sequencing the two futures compiler is losing types. The compiler says that type of result is List[Seq[Product with Serializable]] At the beginning I expect to do something like

```
Future.sequence(List(membersFuture, messagesFuture)).map{ members, messages => ...
```

But it looks like sequencing futures don't work like this... I also tried to using a collect inside the map but I get similar errors.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve with the `sequence` call? I'd just use a for-comprehension instead:

```
val membersFuture: Future[Seq[ConversationMemberModel]] = ConversationMemberPersistence.searchByConversationId(conversationId)
val messagesFuture: Future[Seq[MessageModel]] = MessagePersistence.searchByConversationId(conversationId)

for {
  members <- membersFuture
  messages <- messagesFuture
} yield (self ! ConversationData(members, messages))
```

Note that it is important that you declare the two futures outside the for-comprehension, because otherwise your `messagesFuture` wouldn't be submitted until the `membersFuture` is completed.

You could also use `zip`:

```
membersFuture.zip(messagesFuture).map {
  case (members, messages) => self ! ConversationData(members, messages)
}
```

but I'd prefer the for-comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

When using `Future.sequence`, the assumption is that the underlying types produced by the multiple `Future`s are the same (or extend from the same parent type).  With `sequence`, you basically invert a `Seq` of `Future`s for a particular type to a single `Future` for a `Seq` of that particular type.  A concrete example is probably more illustrative of that point:

```
val f1:Future[Foo] = ...
val f2:Future[Foo] = ...
val f3:Future[Foo] = ...
val futures:List[Future[Foo]] = List(f1, f2, f3)
val aggregateFuture:Future[List[Foo]] = Future.sequence(futures)
```

So you can see that I went from a `List` of `Future[Foo]` to a single `Future` wrapping a `List[Foo]`.  You use this when you already have a bunch of `Future`s for results of the same type (or base type) and you want to aggregate all of the results for the next processing step.  The `sequence` method product a new `Future` that won't be completed until all of the aggregated `Future`s are done and it will then contain the aggregated results of all of those `Future`s.  This works especially well when you have an indeterminate or variable number of `Future`s to process.

For your case, it seems that you have a fixed number of `Future`s to handle.  As @Zoltan suggested, a simple for comprehension is probably a better fit here because the number of `Future`s is known.  So solving your problem like so:

```
for{
  members <- membersFuture
  messages <- messagesFuture
} {
  self ! ConversationData(members, messages)
}
```

is probably the best way to go for this specific example.